# What does「飛んじまいそうです」 mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

Can someone elaborate the structure and the changing of the verb in the sentence? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It's a collapsed way of saying 飛んでしまいそうです.  I think (～し)ちまう/～じまう is colloquial 江戸 or 東京 dialect for (～し)てしまう. (cf. 飛んじゃいそうです。)

breakdown:
とんで -> the てform of 飛ぶ (or the 連用形 of 飛ぶ + 接続助詞「で」)
しまい -> the 連用形 of 補助動詞「しまう」 "end up"
そうです -> the polite form of 助動詞「そうだ」(or the stem of そうだ + 助動詞「です」) "is about to ~" "is likely to ~"

Examples of this contraction:
死んでしまいそうです -> 死んじまいそうです
飲んでしまいそうです -> 飲んじまいそうです
食べてしまいそうです -> 食べちまいそうです
眠ってしまいそうです -> 眠っちまいそうです