# 遠のいちまう - what does it mean?

Tags: phrases

`お前ら二人の故郷も遠のいちまうばっかりだからな`

What does 遠のいちまう mean? I'd guess it has something to do with being far away but the grammar is completely incomprehensible to me. Is this literary usage, or youth slang, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 遠のいてしまう said in the masculine Edo/Kanto accent. 遠【とお】のく is an intransitive verb meaning "to become distant," and しまう is a subsidiary verb meaning "to end up". This contraction is common in fiction (especially middle-aged tough guys and delinquent youths use this). No one around me use ～ちまう in reality, but I think there are real people who use this actively in Kanto.

Related:

- [落としちまった - what form is this?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28324/5010)
- [What does「飛んじまいそうです」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28128/5010)